# make my struct instance 'translate' certain numbers into certain strings

Tags: c, struct, enums

I want to use enums and structs (without using object oriented) to make my program 'translate' the following integers into the specified strings:

1 = "small"

2  = "medium"

3  = "large"

I want something like this: (the known part will be an integer, that has to be translated into the matching string)

`size.num = 3;`

`printf("%s", size.size);`

and the output would be `large`.

---

I tried to do it with two structs:

```
struct Size {
    int num;
    char* type;
}size_map[] = {
    { 1, "small" },
    { 2, "medium" },
    { 3, "large" },
};

struct outfit {
    char* ...;
    char** ....;
    struct Size size;
}T_shirt;

T_shirt.size.num = 3;
```

so when I have only a size in number, I can iterate over the `size_map` to find the matching size (in words) I need.

But is there a simple way to make it automatically 'know' that without the use of `size_map`? (an enum would be also a problem- I will have to use it the opposite way..)

Answer (score 2):

Why not use simple `switch` as below?

```
char *sizeInWord = NULL;

switch(size) {
  case 1:
   sizInWord = "small";
  break;

  case 2:
   sizInWord = "medium";
  break;

  case 3:
   sizInWord = "large";
  break;

  default:
      sizInWord = "InvalidSize";
  break;
}
```

Comment: why is it more simple than what I currently do?

Comment: @J.Y.P. your solution idea is future-proof, e.g. adding `4 = extra large` will still work. a switch() is however not future-proof, and once that 4 is added, it will be "translated" as `InvalidSize`